# KSQL select * from table returns no results and prompt is not responsive

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I'm using kafka-connect to stream rows from a MySQL table into a kafka topic. This is working great.

Then I create a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT, email VARCHAR, gender VARCHAR, first_name VARCHAR, last_name VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='mysql-my-table', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='id');
```

This also works, as I can confirm by doing:

```
LIST TABLES; 
DESCRIBE EXTENDED mytable;
```

I see `mytable`.

The problem is when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Then I get no results and the prompt is unresponsive, I have to press `ctrl+c` to get control back.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying different things and reading the documentation I found the problem.

The field `id` for the messages in my topic are of type ? `INT` and according to KSQL TABLES documentation they need to be of type `VARCHAR`

So I followed the steps to fix this as described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#ksql-key-constraints) and now everything is working fine.

So the steps are as follow:

```
-- Create a stream on the original topic
CREATE STREAM users_with_wrong_key_format (userid INT, username VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

-- Derive a new stream with the required key changes.
-- 1) The CAST statement converts the key to the required format.
-- 2) The PARTITION BY clause re-partitions the stream based on the new, converted key.
CREATE STREAM users_with_proper_key
WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='users-with-proper-key') AS
SELECT CAST(userid as VARCHAR) as userid_string, username, email
FROM users_with_wrong_key_format
PARTITION BY userid_string;

-- Now you can create the table on the properly keyed stream.
CREATE TABLE users_table (userid_string VARCHAR, username VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users-with-proper-key',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
        KEY='userid_string');

-- Now you can create the table on the properly keyed stream.
CREATE TABLE users_table (userid_string VARCHAR, username VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users-with-proper-key',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    KEY='userid_string');
```